# SQL Server - performance for certain partition is slow until restart

Tags: sql-server, optimization, query, partitioning, cpu

On **production environment**, randomly having strange issue.

There are tables **with days as partition** (1,2..31). There is only last 5 day data in tables, there are also tables which doesn't have partitions.

Randomly it starts to slow down queries like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE Partition=@currentDay` and CPU usage is increasing on the server.

Same query with previous day is returning in milliseconds.

If I restart server, **issue is fixed for some time**, maybe 1 week or couple hours and it's coming back.

Same query with (nolock) isn't having issue, but the isolation level is "is_read_committed_snapshot_on".

If I don't restart server, next day there will be issue for @currentDay+1 and @currentDay.

Problem is for all tables with partitions.

There is "always on" activated, when the issue is happening, it's happens both servers. When we disable synchronization and trying queries on secondary DB, which has 0 load, problem persists anyway until service restart.

Can it be issue with MS SQL inconsistency with AMD CPU?
Does it matter it's AMD or Intel?

Version is 15.0.4261.1

Tried `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` but didn't help.

Latest updates, didn't help, **Indexes aren't defragmented**.

Execution plan comparation before and after restart
[image]

Adding detailed execution plans as suggested:

[Plan before restarting the SQL Service](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Hy2dEG3Ks)

[Plan after restarting the SQL Service](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BkbhmznKs)

[image]

[image: Adding index definitions]

Comment: Discussion on this question has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141647/discussion-on-question-by-rezo-sql-server-performance-for-certain-partition-is). Please continue there if needed.

Answer (score 3):

This query is a simple index scan, requiring 356,000 Logical IOs.  However sometimes it takes 104sec of CPU time

```
<QueryTimeStats CpuTime="103975" ElapsedTime="13279" />
```

and sometimes it takes 6.3sec of CPU time

```
 <QueryTimeStats CpuTime="6279" ElapsedTime="788" />
```

This is indeed a mystery.  And I don't have an answer as to why.  If NOLOCK gives you an allocation-order scan which is significantly faster, then perhaps something with the version store (or persistent version store).  Or if it's a VM make sure the hypervisor isn't starving the VM for CPU, which *looks like* high CPU utilization from inside the VM.

However, there *is* a missing index here.  The index you're scanning for the row count is pretty wide, and this is one case where you might want an extra index on just the clustered index columns (or make the PK non-clustered), or add a non-clustered columnstore index so a the rows can be counted by scanning a single compressed column.

Answer (score 2):

I think found the issue, there was long running sp, which was stopped manually from Management Studio in the middle of working.
It caused opened transaction in tempdb, hint about version store made me dig there, thanks to David.
Killing this connection fixed the problem.

I am not sure how this one transaction caused such chain reaction and if it did, why after 5 hours and not immediately. I'm a developer maybe that's the reason of not understanding.

Thank you all for helping me out.
If it was a coincidence and the problem will come back, will post again.

Comment: You might want to add `SET XACT_ABORT ON` to the procedure so future attentions (e.g. cancel from SSMS) will abort the transaction.